# How to make a gitlab changelog entry?

Tags: gitlab

I really, really, don't understand gitlab docs...

I am trying to understand how to make a god damn changelog entry, I have a changelog.md file, here are the gitlab docs about this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/changelog.html

But I don't understand where I have to write that, for example

`$ bin/changelog 'Hey DZ, I added a feature to GitLab!'`

It must be a terminal but where? And what's that '$'...

Comment: ever figure this out? An answer would be great, I'm lost!

Answer (score 0):

> It must be a terminal but where?

Where you have cloned the [GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce).
In that repo, you will find a [`bin/changelog`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/bin/changelog) script, which starts with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, meaning it will execute itself with `ruby`.

And `$` is just a symbol for a shell prompt.

Comment: I did the repo using GitKraken, I don't have any bin in the repository

Comment: oh thats what I have to clone, nope, I didnt, can I clone it in any folder or the same as my repo?

Comment: @Coco in any folder *outside* your repo. And that `bin/changelog` executable if for the GitLab changelog file, not for your own project/repo.

Comment: and how can I make it edit the changelog file from my repo?

Comment: @Coco simply try it from within your repo (`cd /path/to/your/repo; ../gitlab/bin/changelog`) and see if it fails, if you need to adapt that script.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you are reading is for the GitLab development, not for your own project or repository.

Like said in this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632525/gitlab-generate-changelog-script) :

> The bin/changelog script is not a GitLab feature, and does not describe how to generate changelogs for repositories hosted on GitLab
>   ][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632525/gitlab-generate-changelog-script)