# Gitlab Generate Changelog Script

Tags: git, gitlab

Using Gitlab for the first time.

I had an existing web project on my local PC, I ran these commands;

```
cd /myFolder
git init
git add .
git remote add origin remote repository URL
git commit -m "First commit"
git push origin master
```

This added all my files to my remote repo - all working well so far.

I noticed that on the gitlab website, on my project page, there was a button `Add Changelog` (as well as `add readme`, `add licence`, etc.). I clicked this button and an empty `changelog.md` was created in my folder, which i've been able to pull into my local repo.

How do I generate changelog entries?

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/changelog.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384937/how-to-make-a-gitlab-changelog-entry) but I still don't understand.

I can't see a `bin/changelog` anywhere in my local repo.

Do I have to clone the whole [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce) repo somewhere?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/changelog.html#how-to-generate-a-changelog-entry

Comment: It should be wherever the gitlab repo is cloned, this answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384937/how-to-make-a-gitlab-changelog-entry

Comment: How did you install gitlab?

Comment: Please have a quick read through on git basics from a tutorial. `git` is a version control system that exists on your file system, which is also a distributed VCS. You need to `git clone` a repository to work on it locally (i.e. on your PC). `git clone` is basically downloading the file. That's what @OliverRadini asked, where did you download the project? Also, gitlab change log is a Ruby script. The file should be created on your gitlab server, try a `git pull` to update your local repo and use the script according to the documentation

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I think perhaps there's some confusion here about how gitlab works. You can either push your repositories to `gitlab.com` or you can host a version of gitlab yourself. As far as I understand it, you need to be hosting your own version of gitlab in order to automatically generate changelogs using gitlab.

Comment: Gitlab has a slight issue based on the fact that it has three major versions; `gitlab.com`, `gitlab community edition`, and `gitlab enterprise edition`. Knowing which is which when you're looking at documentation isn't always very easy, the url is often an indicator; notice the `ce` in this url: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/changelog.html#how-to-generate-a-changelog-entry

Comment: My bad. @OliverRadini 's answer sounds more educated. I've removed my answer

Comment: @OliverRadini's answer is rather misleading. The `bin/changelog` script is part of the GitLab Development Kit (GDK) used for developing GitLab itself. It's not a general tool for repositories hosted on GitLab. Whether @TheOrdinaryGeek is using CE or EE has no bearing here.

Comment: @OliverRadini TheOrdinaryGeek's commands show a new repository being created. He/she is not developing GitLab, and appears to be confused by the documentation for the development of GitLab CE/EE.The bin/changelog script is not a GitLab feature, and does not describe how to generate changelogs for repositories hosted on GitLab.

Answer (score 9):

No more script needed.

See [GitLab 13.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#create-changelogs-using-the-gitlab-api) (February 2021)

> ### Create changelogs using the GitLab API
>
> Previously, generating a changelog using GitLab was a manual process. Release Managers had to collect all the changes for a given release and then manually add them to a changelog file, which was time-consuming and prone to error. To make this process easier, we have now added an API that will automatically generate a changelog for a given release based on commit history. This enables development teams to better communicate changes to end users by delivering a consistent and comprehensive set of changelogs for every release.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#generate-changelog-data) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-com/gl-infra/-/epics/351).

Example:

```yaml
## 1.0.0 (2021-01-05)

### Features (4 changes)

- [Feature 1](gitlab-org/gitlab@123abc) by @alice ([merge request](gitlab-org/gitlab!123))
- [Feature 2](gitlab-org/gitlab@456abc) ([merge request](gitlab-org/gitlab!456))
- [Feature 3](gitlab-org/gitlab@234abc) by @steve
- [Feature 4](gitlab-org/gitlab@456)
```

---

And, May 2023, [glab 1.30.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/releases/v1.30.0) adds:

[`glab changelog generate`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/4f200f917e5b09af5f9865b128be01a76f88caf7/docs/source/changelog/generate.md), which does the same, through the `glab` CLI.

This is mentioned with [GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/#create-a-changelog-from-the-gitlab-cli) (June 2023)

> ### Create a changelog from the GitLab CLI
>
> Changelogs generate comprehensive lists of changes based on commits to a project. They can be challenging to automate or view, and require interacting with the GitLab API.
>
> With the release of [GitLab CLI v1.30.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/releases/v1.30.0) you can now generate changelogs for projects directly from your shell. The `glab changelog generate` command makes it easier to review, automate, and publish changelogs.
>
> Thanks [Michael Mead](https://gitlab.com/michael-mead) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/changelogs.html#from-the-gitlab-cli) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/issues/1292).

Comment: I like this feature but the problem is tat in a commit you can't put more than one type of Changelog. I have tryed to put multiple type but only the last is chosen

Comment: @Macdeveloper Good point. That would be a good feature request to add to the team who proposed that feature: https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-com/gl-infra/-/issues

Comment: thank you, but in the list of the project at the link you proposed I don't find any project for the api management

Comment: @Macdeveloper I mentioned them because they are involved in https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-com/gl-infra/-/epics/351

Comment: ok i will do it, meanwhile I forked a good go software cli (https://juhani.gitlab.io/go-semrel-gitlab/) that create changelog using semrel syntax and work perfectly integrated into gitlab CI. I start forking go-semrel (https://github.com/bisegni/go-semrel)  lib for producing many change for one commit and then forked go-semrel-gitlab (https://gitlab.com/bisegni/go-semrel-gitlab) to use it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you how you'd like to manage `changelog.md`. Take a look at other questions like [Good ways to manage a changelog using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523534/good-ways-to-manage-a-changelog-using-git#22492425) for examples of generating changelogs from git commit messages.

The documentation you linked to is about generating changelogs for the GitLab projects ([ce](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce)/[ee](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee)). It's not a feature for repositories hosted on GitLab.

Comment: This answers a separate question, there are lots of ways to generate changelogs, this concerns generating those logs using gitlab